# Update table with removing old values

Tags: mysql

I have a very simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `comment` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='no';
```

I would need to be able to run update this table, with various VALUES. For example, sometimes I would have, 3 inserts, sometimes 6 inserts. They all have same user_id, but the **comment** changes.
When the update is run, the old values should be first deleted, and the new ones inserted. This is what I have tried:

```
REPLACE INTO test (
user_id,
comment
)
VALUES
(111, 'ANDROID'),
(111, 'IOS')
```

This statement inserts only last value (IOS). My expectation was to have both values (ANDROID and IOS).

Now If I run this:

```
REPLACE INTO mama (
user_id,
name
)
VALUES
(111, 'COMMODORE'),
(111, 'SINCLAIR'),
(111, 'AMIGA')
```

I expect to have all three values.

If I run this:

```
REPLACE INTO test (
user_id,
name
)
VALUES
(111, 'SINCLAIR')
```

I would expect to only have SINCLAIR.

What I need to do to have make it happen?

Comment: You need `INSERT` not `REPLACE` and the table needs to be redesigned

Comment: Would you please elaborate what changes? :)

Comment: `user_id` could no longer be a primary key since it'd throw an error on duplicate key, I'd switch to a unique comment_id as the primary.

Comment: I need user_id to be a primary key. This table is going to be accessed by another service, which only knows user_id

Comment: You can still reference the user_id column, even add it as a secondary key for optimization but primary keys can not be duplicates it's against the rules of SQL

Comment: I understand. But with this approach, the previous values are not removed. Name can change, but the old ones remain

Comment: Nick has a good answer below, demonstrating what I said. If that doesn't answer this question perhaps you need to elaborate more on the end goal and why `user_id` must be primary and not a index key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PRIMARY` keys **must** be unique. So when you replace with `(111, 'IOS')` it replaces any existing entry with `user_id = 111`, hence you end up with only `(111, 'IOS')` in the table. If you want to insert all the values, you need to remove the `PRIMARY KEY` on `user_id` (perhaps replace it with an index). For example:

```
ALTER TABLE test DROP PRIMARY KEY;
ALTER TABLE test ADD INDEX (user_id);
REPLACE INTO test (
user_id,
comment
)
VALUES
(111, 'ANDROID'),
(111, 'IOS');

SELECT *
FROM test
```

Output:

```
user_id     comment
111         ANDROID
111         IOS
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=41dc009fa11961f4f6919c1d997c650e)

Note that once you remove the `PRIMARY KEY` on `user_id`, `REPLACE` becomes the same as `INSERT`, thus you can insert the same values multiple times. If this is not what you want, consider an `UNIQUE` key on `comment`:

```
ALTER TABLE test ADD UNIQUE (comment)
```

This will prevent duplicate `(user_id, comment)` combinations.

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=906f4c67c4468fd54edee56fda06f52a)

Comment: Awesome. Would work for me, but I can't have old values. Is there a way to remove the old ones, before inserting the new ones.

Comment: So when you say `insert (111, 'ANDROID')` you want there to *only* be that value for that `user_id`? If so, you would need to `DELETE FROM test WHERE user_id=111` first.

Comment: Yes, indeed. So I need to delete first WHERE user_id, and then insert new ones?

Comment: Exactly. See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=5657904c6ce18a3741890359b9df015c

Comment: If it is easier, I can have two tables with foreign key as well, just I am unsure how to proceed.

Comment: For what you describe I think delete then insert is the only way to go.

Comment: Awesome. Is there a better approach. I can have two tables, maybe one that hold an entry, and another one with the comments?

Comment: You would still need to delete the entries from the second table before you inserted new ones.

Comment: Thank you for the time and patience. Things are more clear now!